# How to import org.apache.commons.collections repository

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, maven, apache-commons

I'm new to web java programming. I need to use this package `org.apache.commons.collections`. The problem is that I don't know which repository I need to use in order to find the proper artifact. Is there a catalog with repositories?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavens default repo will get you pretty far. You can search for artifacts online in a lot of places for example [jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/)

Comment: I added the artifact http://pastebin.com/RM0dxxAL and I can successfully compile my file. But when I deploy it on Glassfish server I get this error: http://pastebin.com/wZPTRUCB  Waht can cause this error?

Comment: Post a new question for that and please include the relevant parts of the server.log as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two more:

http://mvnrepository.com

http://www.mvnbrowser.com

Answer (score 1):

The official search page for Maven Central (where Maven downloads from) is:

http://search.maven.org